# Connection between child and parent

Tags: flutter, callback, state

I created my own TextField widget and i want to use onChange() function of textField, so i created a callbackFunction as you can see below, im trying to print given param of function but receiving null, how can i handle these callbacks;

**CallBack Function**

```
void childCallBack(dynamic value, dynamic property) {
    setState(() {
      property = value;
    });
  }
```

**How i call my TextField in main state**

```
TextFieldForProduct(
                property: widget.product.name,
                func: childCallBack,
                      )
```

**And my CustomTextFieldWidget**

```
class TextFieldForProduct extends StatelessWidget {
  TextFieldForProduct({@required this.property, @required this.func});
  var property;
  Function func;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
    
     child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: TextField(
          onChanged: (value) {
            func(value, property);
          },
         
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the point of passing widget.product.name to TextFieldForProduct, you can directly set the widget.product.name = value; in the childCallBack since both are available in the same class. Please see the code below:

```
  void childCallBack(String value) {
    setState(() {
      widget.product.name = value;
    });
  }
```

How to call TextField in main state :

```
  TextFieldForProduct(
       func: childCallBack,
   ),
```

**CustomTextFieldWidget**

```
class TextFieldForProduct extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextFieldForProduct({@required this.func});
  final Function func;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: TextField(
          onChanged: (String value) => func(value),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's so true, thanks a lot, getting confused about state management sometimes.